# Is there someway to export AdWords data which would enable me to match gclid id's to campaigns?

Tags: export, google-ads-api

We have captured hundreds of ppc leads from multiple adwords campaigns however we only have the GCLID id for each.

I want to be able to match glid id'd to google adwords campaigns.  Is there a way to export glid id's from adwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. There is no API method which allows you to match the gclid's with your AdWords data. It's only available internally for Google to link Analytics data to AdWords data, and it seems that Google doesn't want anyone else to be able to do that.

Comment: This response is outdated.  The Click Performance Report in the AdWords API provides what you need.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports#click - maybe new option in reporting adwrods api

Comment: Please avoid link only answers.